# Wireshark Lua dissector utf16 string

Tags: lua, utf-16, wireshark-dissector

I am writing a custom Wireshark Lua dissector. One field in the dissector is a UTF16 string. I tried to specify this field with

```lua
msg_f = ProtoField.string("mydissector.msg", "msg", base.UNICODE)
local getMsg = buffer(13) -- starting on byte 13
subtree:add_le(m.msg_f, getMsg)
```

However, this only adds the first character rather than the whole string. It also raises an Expert Info warning undecoded trailing/stray characters.

What is the correct way to parse a UTF16 string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with is simply:

```lua
msg_f = ProtoField.string("mydissector.msg", "msg")
local getMsg = buffer(13) -- starting on byte 13
local msg = getMsg:le_ustring()
subtree:add(msg_f,  getMsg, msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the *range* of bytes that comprises the string.  This is typically determined by either an explicit length field or by a NULL-terminator.  The exact method of determining the range is dependent upon the particular protocol and field in question.

An example of each type:

- If there's a length field, say of 1 byte in length that precedes the string, then you can use something like:

```
    local str_len = buffer(13, 1):le_uint()

    subtree:add_le(m.msg_len_f, buffer(13))
    if str_len > 0 then
        subtree:add_le(m.msg_f, buffer(14, str_len))
    end
```

- And if the string is NULL-terminated, you can use something like:

```
    local str = buffer(13):stringz()
    local str_len = str:len()
    subtree:add_le(m.msg_f, buffer(13, str_len + 1))
```

These are just pseudo-examples, so you'll need to apply whatever method, possibly none of these, to fit your data.

Refer to the [Wireshark's Lua API Reference Manual](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Tree.html) for more details, or to the Wireshark [LuaAPI](https://wiki.wireshark.org/LuaAPI) wiki pages.